# How to get the coordinates of several points on the circle with php

Tags: php

I have a few points. I need to put those points on a circle and get their coordinates.

```
function positionX($numItems,$thisNum){ 
  $alpha = 360/$numItems; // angle between the elements
  $r = 1000; // radius
  $angle = $alpha * $thisNum; // angle for N element
  $x = $r * cos($angle); // X coordinates
  return $x;
}

function positionY($numItems,$thisNum){ 
  $alpha = 360/$numItems; // angle between the elements
  $r = 1000; // radius
  $angle = $alpha * $thisNum; // angle for N element
  $y = $r * sin($angle); // Y coordinates
  return $y;
}
```

But my code isn't work.. These functions produce strange coordinates.

image example: http://cl.ly/image/453E2w1Y0w0d

**UPD:**

```
echo positionX(4,1)."<br>";
echo positionY(4,1)."<br><br>";

echo positionX(4,2)."<br>";
echo positionY(4,2)."<br><br>";

echo positionX(4,3)."<br>";
echo positionY(4,3)."<br><br>";

echo positionX(4,4)."<br>";
echo positionY(4,4)."<br><br>";
```

4 - All elements;
1,2,3,4 - Number of element.

These code gives me result:

```
-448.073616129
893.996663601

-598.460069058
0

984.381950633
-176.045946471

-283.691091487
958.915723414
```

On the circle it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cos() and sin() functions expect the argument in radians, not in degrees.

Use the [deg2rad()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php) function to convert

**EDIT**

CODE:

```
function positionX($numItems,$thisNum){
  $alpha = 360/$numItems; // angle between the elements
  $r = 1000; // radius
  $angle = $alpha * $thisNum; // angle for N element
  $x = $r * cos(deg2rad($angle)); // X coordinates
  return $x;
}

function positionY($numItems,$thisNum){
  $alpha = 360/$numItems; // angle between the elements
  $r = 1000; // radius
  $angle = $alpha * $thisNum; // angle for N element
  $y = $r * sin(deg2rad($angle)); // Y coordinates
  return $y;
}

echo round(positionX(4,1))."<br>";
echo round(positionY(4,1))."<br><br>";

echo round(positionX(4,2))."<br>";
echo round(positionY(4,2))."<br><br>";

echo round(positionX(4,3))."<br>";
echo round(positionY(4,3))."<br><br>";

echo round(positionX(4,4))."<br>";
echo round(positionY(4,4))."<br><br>";
```

RESULTS:

```
0
1000

-1000
0

-0
-1000

1000
-0
```

Comment: i have the same result with strange coordinates

Comment: In that case, give details: values of $numItems and $thisNum, what you expect, and what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are not using radiants in your sin() and cos() functions. You need to convert angels into radiants. Look at the [function description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sin.php) of sin(), there you find that the arg is in radiants.

Reminder

```
1° = 2 PI / 360;
```

**Edit**

I can't seem to find the error in your code, try this one instead

```
function($radius, $points, $pointToFind) {

 $angle = 360 / $points * 2 * pi(); //angle in radiants

 $x = $radius * cos($angle * $pointToFind);
 $y = $radius * sin($angle * $pointToFind);

}
```

Comment: I edited a bit from my old post. Dont know what the problem is with your code. Could be that Mark Baker is correct and you are giving wrong input paramters

Comment: your code gives me coordinates like -3.52698278154E-11, but i need a numeric coordinates, how to get it from this?